# Django: filter a queryset based on a 3 step foreign key connection

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a bunch of models, related through the user model:`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Model 1:

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Model 2:

```
class Block(models.Model):
    ...
    current_teacher = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Model 3:

```
class CourseStudent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block)
    ...
```

Given two Users one is a `teacher` in the BLock model, and the other is a `student` user in the other two models, how can I get a query set of Submissions, where:
(apologies, I'm struggling with how to best describe this)

- CourseStudent.user = Submission.user
- CourseStudent.block is one of the Blocks that has current_teacher=teacher

In other words: teachers teach specific Blocks, students have courses in those blocks.  Students submit work.  Teachers only want to see work submitted by students in their (the teacher's) block.

or

I want all Submissions by a User where user --> CourseStudent --> block --> current_teacher, for a given teacher.

Comment: You want all submissions by a user right under the teacher?

Comment: I want all submissions by a user where user --> CourseStudent --> block --> teacher, for a given teacher.

Comment: Yes, and the way to tell if the user is under the teacher is by looking at the Block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
Submission.objects.filter(user__coursestudent__block__current_teacher=teacher).distinct()
```

You start with the thing you want ("a query set of `Submissions`") and then work your way across the relationships. The purpose of `distinct()` is to get rid of duplicate results. (For example, if a user has the same teacher in two different blocks, the `Submission` will appear twice without it).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that will definitely help me in the future.  It's the foreign key reversal (`user__coursestudent` in this case) that I have difficulty intuiting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another relation between Block and Submission, because as you said only students submit. So if you filter user --> CourseStudent --> block --> current_teacher then you'd get Submissions by the 'Teacher', no? Or perhaps I'm missing something.